# Linux USB Boot results in black screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, intel, kms

I'm trying to install Linux alongside Windows 8 on my new Asus Zenbook UX32VD, which has both an Intel HD 4000 and a NVidia 620M

I've been having quite a few problems booting up linux via USB so I can install it. So far, I've tried Linux Mint Debian edition, Crunchbang, Debian, and Ubuntu.

What usually happens is that after the initial loading, I see the mouse cursor for a couple of seconds, and then the screen goes black, for good. The rest of the system seems to keep going, but I have no image whatsoever, and have to shutdown the hard way.

However, in some of my attempts with Ubuntu and Mint, I managed to boot. What changed those times? I have no clue.
In one of those attempts, I finished the instalation of Mint, but after rebooting to the installed system, the same problem occurred

I also tried adding boot options, particularly `nomodeset`, and `i915.modeset=1 driver=intel`. The first time I tried each of them, Mint booted correctly, making me think it was the solution. But later attempts resulted in the same black screen

But with Debian, it seems everything goes well, and I managed to install it. But I'm currently having some problems configuring the system, particularly the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys (any tips on that?)

So, my question is, how should I proceed in order to boot correctly, knowing that this is probably some kind of problem with detecting the graphics card?
I realize that newer laptops are very likely to have problems like these, but if there's a solution for it already, I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: There is no real question.

Comment: I think the question is pretty much obvious, even though i didn't ask it explicitly. but i'll edit it since you asked

Comment: When you boot normally and get the blank screen, can you see (in some strong light or smth) the desktop? (It would mean that display backlight is off).

Comment: Have you tried disabling one video card and checking the results? Most probably there is a conflict with the system choosing the default one.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install [ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) minimal and not install desktop environment. When your install finished, login to console and then install xorg, latest drivers from [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) and your desirable DE. Then, run `startx` and see what happens.

Comment: I did as you suggested. First of all, i had to install the Xubuntu packages from the Ubuntu minimal setup, otherwise i could not get any internet connection (both Wifi, and usb-to-ethernet, which is my laptop has available)
After installing, i got the same black screen, but was now able to use ```nomodeset``` to get a root console. However, trying to install the nvidia drivers or bumblebee from there, resulted once again in a black screen. Only now, even ```nomodeset``` works, so i got to a dead end